# How to set android:icon dynamically

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using react-native-config to be able to build using different environments. One of the purposes is to have different icons depending on the environment. I got this to work on iOS but having trouble on Android.

I have a @string resource:
`<string name="exchange_name">@string/REACT_APP_EXCHANGE_NAME</string>`

The REACT_APP_EXCHANGE_NAME variable is inserted from my .env file (react-native-config magic).
My question is how can I have different icons depending on the value of that string resource?

Something like:
`android:icon={exchange_name == 'something' ? @mipmap/icon1 : @mipmap/icon2}`

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, found a way: Gradle productFlavors.

```
    productFlavors{
        env_1 {
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                appIcon: "@mipmap/splash_icon_1"
            ]
        }

        env_2 {
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                appIcon: "@mipmap/splash_icon_2"
            ]
        }
    }
```

To run:

`npx react-native run-android --variant env_1`

Comment: You can also consider using this package to change the icon from the code during runtime, instead of before runtime. https://github.com/skb1129/react-native-change-icon